# Encode URL picked up by Digg Digg

Tags: plugins, social-sharing

I have found the following JavaScript to encode. It's just I don't know where to plug it into Digg Digg plugin.

```
encodeURIComponent(location.href)
```

How can I customize / modify Digg Digg plugin (Facebook share) so it will picked up URL by encoding first ?

Comment: What is the Digg Digg plugin you are using?

Comment: facebook share..

Comment: Facebook or Digg? These are two different services. Add the URL of the plugin’s source code to your question.

Comment: I am using Digg Digg plugin. Within the plugin I can opt to have Facebook share.